# choose database type: sql or nosql

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture, nosql

I have a non-standard task to create an application objects management. The objects are houses, which now have more than 40 characteristics.

At first I start from db architecture.

Basic introductory:

1. The set of characteristics can change (in the future at the view-layer in administration part of application
2. It is necessary to store the history of changes of characteristics of objects (CRUD operations). Also I need to save date from which concrete characteristic has come into effect (the specificity of the system).
3. It is necessary to separate the access to the fields and records of objects (for example first user sees one at home, second another home, first user is accessible to one field, another to other fields), and users have to differentiate the rights to actions (CRUD).
4. In the future, this data will be used for DataWarehouse to build OLAP.

Question: Which type of database to choose now based on this requirements that I will have minimum problems in future?

Initially, as a person working with .NET technologies it was thought to create everything on an MSSQL server with separate tables for fields/values ​​and make tables for roles also with ManyToMany bindings for restricting user actions.

But I don't like this way, because it don't use relational databases basics.

Also I think about NoSQL, but I'm interested in that: how can I configure the access rights system to the fields and manage them? And also how to syncronize NoSQL with OLAP?

Or may be now we have any frameworks, which give ability for this requirements.

Colleagues, which recommendation could you give for me?

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, there are plenty of content management systems that deal with customisable, ACL-enforced metadata. I struggle to understand why it would not use the relational basics - of course the relational model cannot completely guarantee the consistency of the model, but so wouldn't the non-relational one.

I think that this ultimately boils down to what you feel most productive and comfortable with.

Comment: Alessandro, Thank you for your answer. And could you give examples of CMS systems, which provide support of ACL-enforced metadata?